# Why was this character's career considered to be over?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

At the end of ST:DIS 3x05,

> Nhan decides to stay with Barzan scientist Attis on the Tikhov.

Her rationale is that he does not want to leave the ship

> where his dead family rests. He is terminally ill himself from the event that killed his family.

As far as I understood, the crew of the Thikov is a rotating assignment, anyway, so all Federation members are in charge of the ship from time to time.

However,

> Burnham points out that Nhan staying on the Tikhov means her Starfleet career is over.

**Why is that?** Wouldn't it mean at best an extended leave until the next regular crew for the ship can be assigned?

> Or, if you will, until she has stuck around for Attis' family to get a proper burial?

Especially with the current state of Starfleet and the Federation, it doesn't seem like they can be overly picky if a capable, trained officer were to rejoin even after a prolonged absence.

Comment: A better question might be why are they expecting a career in this kind of context when they are a millennia out of date? I see your last performance review was in December... a thousand years ago, what have you done since then to be ready for a promotion?

Comment: @Jontia: Given that Starfleet seemed eager to reassign the crew to new postings, they didn't seem to share that concern. And as Georgiou's 23rd century tricks to manipulate holograms still work, apparently not that much has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that she wants to return to Barzan. [From the transcript](https://subslikescript.com/series/Star_Trek_Discovery-5171438/season-3/episode-5)

> Considering what Airiam and I went through, let's just say... I'm good here.
> I'll make sure Attis's family gets home for a proper burial.
> And that the first Barzan watch is completed successfully.
> And I'd like to see my home again.
> I never thought I would.

The entire episode is constantly dropping hints she is nostalgic for her home.

Comment: So what? Is there any reason to believe she could not continue being a Starfleet officer after returning from Barzan, or even while staying there?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Again, the series is implying she's going to finish the mission there and then return to Barzan. Since she left Starfleet, the implication is she'd have to pick back up where she left off. In other words, this is an opportunity cost for her.